# How can I perform arbitrary computation in OpenGL ES 3.0 (prior to compute shaders)

Tags: opengl-es

Prior to the introduction of compute shaders in OpenGL ES 3.1, what techniques or tricks can be used to perform general computations on the GPU?  e.g. I am animating a particle system and I'd like to farm out some work to the GPU.  Can I make use of vertex shaders with "fake" vertex data somehow?

EDIT:

I found this example which looks helpful:  http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/01/05/exploring_gpgpu_on_ios/

Answer (score 1):

You can use vertex shaders and transform feedback to output the results to an application accessible buffer. The main downside is that  you can't have cross-thread data sharing between "work items" like you can with a compute shader, so they are not 100% equivalent.